# App crashing while taking values from XML

Tags: android, xml, web-services

I am trying to get url and thumb from the xml by webservice. I am getting the xml but it is crashing while processing the xml.

This is my code:

```
String tmpstr = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();
        xpp.setInput(new StringReader(tmpstr));
        int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                if (xpp.getName().toString().equals("url")) {
                    eventType = xpp.nextToken();
                    if (eventType == XmlPullParser.CDSECT) {
                        videourl = videourl + xpp.getText() + ",";
                    }
                } else if (xpp.getName().toString().equals("thumb_image")) {
                    eventType = xpp.nextToken();
                    if (eventType == XmlPullParser.CDSECT) {
                        thumbimage = thumbimage + xpp.getText() + ",";
                    }
                }
            }

            eventType = xpp.next();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I myself have exprerienced many times. when u make any change in the xml and just build your project and run it the app crashes.  If you clean your code instead of building it your problem of crash should get resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Try using SAX Parser ... its easier to use and faster and might also solve ur issue .. http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=152

Answer (score 0):

ok i have resolved the problem. It was an XML oriented problem.

Thanks everyone for all help and comments :)